# Nested resources, Ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are two models: 
Exams and Resources.

Every each exam could has many Resources

Routes.rb

```
resources :exams do
    resources :resources
end
```

I want to get asynchronously all resources belongs to particular Exam.
That should be realising in exam controller, yes?

But there's another problem, how should I send ajax request? I need to make it on_succes of another Ajax request (adding resource at the particular exam page). It is done by form_for with :remote, json returned by controller and js (jquery) file wich registers callbacks for ajax states.

[Here are sources](http://github.com/rbklaser/rbklaser), An Ajax Branch.

Summary: I can add a resource to an exam (at /exams/:id) with Ajax but i want to reload Exam.resources when first Ajax is finished.

Please, Help me!

Answer (score 0):

I did that.

Just returning json'ed @resource (which was just added) and inject it to page via jquery when ajax request is successed